# How to marshall the nested content of a class but without adding the attribute name as its key

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

I have this class:

```
public class EnvironmentInformation implements Serializable {

    private final String[] profiles;

    //GETTERS/SETTERS
```

An object of this class is added to a map with a key "environment". When I marshall the map using Jackson's object mapper I get:

```
{"environment":{"profiles":["dev"]}}
```

However what I would like to get is:

```
{"environment": ["dev"]}
```

Is there any way to customize the marshalling process to get that result?

Notice I cannot modify the EnvironmentInformation class structure (I could add annotations though),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved implementing JsonSerializable:

```
public class EnvironmentInformation implements Serializable, JsonSerializable {

    private final String[] profiles;

    public EnvironmentInformation(String[] environment) {
        this.profiles = environment;
    }

    public String[] getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (String fooValue : getProfiles()) {
            gen.writeString(fooValue);
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        serialize(gen, serializers);
    }
}
```